# iOS: Universal app won't rotate, never calls willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation

My (Universal iPhone/iPad) app will not rotate. In all of my viewcontrollers I return "YES" to the method shouldRotate, but my viewcontrollers' willRotateToInterfaceOrientation methods never get called.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: You should probably just double check that you don't have orientation lock on. You know, before we all go insane trying to test this :P

Comment: It acts like this on the iPad Simulator and an actual iPad.

Comment: Aurum: I've wasted 10mins trying to figure our what the hell is going on before stumbling upon your comment! Doh!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that universal app are you using a splitViewController? If so make sure all your viewControllers return Yes to should autoRotate.

I passed an array of viewControllers (actually NavigationViewControllers) to a splitViewController and my view did not rotate. This was because my left hand viewController was not implementing shouldAutorotate. I think this is because rotation on an iPad when you use a splitViewController is different then on an iPhone. When rotated it shows two viewControllers. Both have to support landscape mode i guess?

If you do not want the rotation of the one viewController to rotate do a conditional check to see if you are on an iPad in the shouldAutoRotate method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a tab bar? You will need to subclass your tabbar controller and return yes for should rotate.

Comment: Are you sure? I never needed to do that. I just return YES for shouldRotate in all the tab bar's view controllers, but not for the tab bar itself.

Comment: I'm using a custom view controller, based off of [link]http://www.pushplay.net/2009/05/wed-may-6-2009-816p-framework-for-having-multiple-views-in-an-iphone-app/ but adapted for NIBs and universal applications.

Comment: I'll throw my vote in for this one; it worked for me. I don't want to rotate the tab bar on my iPhone, but on the iPad, I do — and I had to subclass `UITabBarController` for autorotation support. Didn't matter if I subclassed `UISplitViewController` or not (I tried with and without).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. The solution was to subclass UISplitViewController and add

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Even though the individual view controllers were already returning YES, it didn't work until I added the split view controller subclass.